# Running bash script in python script on jenkins causes running this script before everything

Tags: python, bash, jenkins

I have in my case Jenkins job which has building script in its configuration. Inside that script I am running parameterized Python script. At the end of python script I am running parameterized bash *.sh* script. Problem is, that eventhough it is in code at the end it is running actually on the very begining of python script, and haven't been ran at the place where it supposed to be. I was usign `osRun`, `os.system`, `subprocess` in order to run bash script inside python but the result is the same. Does anyone have a clue where to look for an error.

Comment: It would be helpful if you post a sample of your script here and how you are calling the Python script in your freestyle or pipeline job, etc.

Comment: Most probably your script is running in proper order but the output is being buffered. Try adding the `-u` (unbuffered) option while running the Python script as in `python -u script.py`.